# How do I create a "two layer" lists using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm going for something similar to the classic iPhone "Swipe to reveal" look using
CSS [image: an example]

the code structure I'm aiming for is something like like

```
<ul>
    <li>Top Content</li>
    <li>Bottom Content</li>
</ul>
```

So that using javascript and css transition I can get the top layer to slide away and reveal the bottom layer. I've tried setting the bottom layer to top: -(height of li) and z-index -1 which sort of works (they do overlap) except there is a large space between the divs due to this (margin 0 padding 0 didn't fix that)

How else could I implement this?

Comment: Can't you just give the `ul` a background image/color?

Comment: Dutchie432 did you just look at the picture and not read the question at all?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your request. Would a conventional accordion accomplish what you're after? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @edude05 No. Thanks for asking. Obviously the request you're making is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I really think using same list to accomplish this is a terrible idea you should just use two different ul's http://jsfiddle.net/8JYA2/

```
<ul class="list-1">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-2">
  <li>Back One</li>
  <li>Back Two</li>
  <li>Back Three</li>
  <li>Back Four</li>
</ul>
```

I might be wrong but why are you aiming with that code structure?

Comment: Your solution works really well and I'm leaning toward doing it this way. The only reason I wanted to do it in one list was because the <li>s are generated in a loop. Two lists are doable but I'll either have to use two loops or think of a ingenious way to do it in one

Comment: Well I think this approach will be better, faster and easier to work with because if you start playing with css child selectors you might lose time when dealing with iOS 6 rendering, atleast that's how I see it anyways good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution now after a bit of help and experimenting.

The solution was to to make one list, but put two divs per li and layer the divs. 
Then using javascript, modify the left and right percentage on the divs so that the top div slides off. The code looks something like this

```
<ul>
  <li><div>Top Content</div></li>
  <li><div>Bottom Content</div></li>
</ul>
```

Combined with what I figured out before regarding setting the z-index higher on the top content it works great.